# lastnames to firstnames dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I'm given a dictionary containing people's friend's circle, and I'm supposed to create a dictionary organizing these people based on their lastnames i.e. a lastname to firstname dictionary.

```
people_and_friends = {'Jay Pritchett': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Gloria Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'], 'Claire Dunphy': ['Jay Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy'], 'Manny Delgado': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Luke Dunphy'], 'Mitchell Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'], 'Alex Dunphy': ['Luke Dunphy'], 'Cameron Tucker': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett'], 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy': ['Dylan D-Money', 'Gilbert D-Cat'], 'Phil Dunphy': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'], 'Dylan D-Money': ['Chairman D-Cat', 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy'], 'Gloria Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'], 'Luke Dunphy': ['Alex Dunphy', 'Manny Delgado', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy']}
```

This is the code I have so far which isolates the lastnames of the individuals in the first dictionary:

```
lastnames_to_firstnames = {}

for people in person_and_friends:
    family = person[person.rfind(' '):].strip()
    if not family in lastnames_to_firstnames:
        lastnames_to_firstnames[family_name] = person_and_friends[people]
```

The lastnames_to_firstnames should look like this:

```
lastname_firstname = {'Pritchett':['Jay', 'Gloria', 'Mitchell'], 
'Dunphy':['Alex', 'Claire', 'Haley Gwendolyn', 'Luke', 'Phil'], 
'Delgado':['Manny'],'Tucker':['Cameron'],'D-Money':['Dylan'], 'D-Car':
['Chairman']}
```

I can't figure out how to organize the values of the first dictionary. Any help?

Comment: What do you want the `lastname_to_firstnames` dictionary to look like?

Comment: it should look like lastnames_firstname

Comment: @AbbyLiu I think you need to place the format in which you want the `lastnames_to_firstnames` into the question, it will help people understand what you want quickly. The less mental headache they have whilst checking your question the quicker they can get to answering it.

Comment: i just updated that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

people_and_friends = {'Joseph Hazelton': ['Penny Patrick', 'Paul Paulson'], 
                     'Gilbert Gunderson': ['Philip Patrick', 'Jenny Paulson'], 
                     'Helena Anderson': ['Penny Patrick', 'Dylan D-Money']}

for k, v in people_and_friends.items():
    for first, last in map(str.split, (k, *v)):
        d[last].append(first)
```

Edit:

As TitanFighter points out below, if you want to avoid duplicate name pairing, you can use a `set` instead by replacing

```
d = defaultdict(set)
```

and

```
d[last].add(first)
```

Edit the Second:

If you can't use `defaultdict` you can roll your own like this

```
d = {}

people_and_friends = {'Joseph Hazelton': ['Penny Patrick', 'Paul Paulson'], 
                     'Gilbert Gunderson': ['Philip Patrick', 'Jenny Paulson'], 
                     'Helena Anderson': ['Penny Patrick', 'Dylan D-Money']}

for k, v in people_and_friends.items():
    for first, last in map(str.split, (k, *v)):
        if last in d:
            d[last].append(first)
        else:
            d[last] = [first]
```

3dit:

The problem is that some people in your dictionary have three names: `Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy`.  So what we'll do is collect all of the names except for the last one into a list, then join that list again into a string

```
d = {}

for k, v in people_and_friends.items():
    for *first, last in map(str.split, (k, *v)):
        first = ' '.join(first)
        if last in d:
            d[last].add(first)
        else:
            d[last] = {first}
```

Comment: Would be better to use `set` instead of `list`. Check `'Patrick': ['Penny', 'Philip', 'Penny']`

Comment: i'm not allowed to import anything

Comment: Hi Patrick, your addition helps with smaller dictionaries but returns 'too many values to unpack' for larger ones

Comment: Do you have some names that have more than just a first name and a last name?

Comment: Nope, I don't. If it helps, this is the exact people_and_friends dictionary I have:

Comment: I have edited the question to add my exact people_to_friends dictionary that's giving me problems